# React & SCSS: SassError: Undefined variable

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, node-sass

I am developing a React application and I have SCSS file where I have defined some variables:

**variables.scss**:

```css
$source-sans-font: Source Sans Pro, serif;
$sidebar-bg-color: #916fdd;
$sidebar-width: 250px;
$icon-bg-color: transparent;
$icon-size: 24px;
$highlight-color: #ffffff;
$breakpoint-lg: 1100px;
```

In my React component I have an other SCSS file which uses this variables:

```css
@use "../../assets/scss/variables";
    
.headerText {
  font-family: $source-sans-font;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #2d2d2d;
  opacity: 1;
  padding-top: 9px;
}
```

When I try to run the application I am getting this error:

Failed to compile.

```
./src/components/PortfolioSummary/PortfolioSummary.module.scss
(./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-7-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--5-oneOf-7-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-7-4!./src/components/PortfolioSummary/PortfolioSummary.module.scss)
SassError: Undefined variable: "$source-sans-font".
         on line 4 of /Users/olcayertas/10n/src/components/PortfolioSummary/PortfolioSummary.module.scss
>>   font-family: $source-sans-font;
 
------------------^
```

I am using WebStorm and IDE doesn't give any error for the variables and if I pressed command + click on variables it can go to the definitions.

> Environment:
> Node: v14.17.0
> NPM: 6.14.13
> OS: Mac OS X Big Sur

Comment: Did you try `@import` rule instead of `@use`? I don't suggest you switching to the `@import` rule, just something to check :) make sure you are using `dart-sass` as `node-sass` doesn't work with `@use` rule.

Comment: make sure installed node-sass in your project, and use `@import` instant `@use`

Comment: But the SCSS documentation says they will drop to use at-import and suggests to use at-use.
https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import

Comment: I have node-sass installed.

Comment: Md. Abu Sayed bad suggestion - [The Sass team discourages the continued use of the @import rule.](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import)

Comment: @OlcayErtaş check [webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/) on how to use `dart-sass` (assuming you are using webpack)

Comment: please provide any code link use Code pen or code sandbox

Comment: Thanks guys! I have solved the problem. There was a file watcher which I previously added. That watcher was compiling scss to css in same folder. That was the problem.

Answer (score 2):

for above issue either you have call variable like

```
 @use "../../assets/scss/variables";
    
 .headerText {
  font-family: variables.$source-sans-font;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #2d2d2d;
  opacity: 1;
  padding-top: 9px;
}
```

or while import give alias name

```
@use "../../assets/scss/variables" as variable;
    
.headerText {
  font-family: variable.$source-sans-font;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #2d2d2d;
  opacity: 1;
  padding-top: 9px;
}
```

else

````
@use "../../assets/scss/variables" as *;
    
.headerText {
  font-family: $source-sans-font;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #2d2d2d;
  opacity: 1;
  padding-top: 9px;
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

If you have node-sass installed, I'd suggest you use this snippet below

```
@import "../../assets/scss/variables";

.headerText {
  font-family: $source-sans-font;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #2d2d2d;
  opacity: 1;
  padding-top: 9px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When importing the SCSS files into the main SCSS file make sure you use
@import ''; on all files.
**Do not use** @import URL(path to your file);.
They are not the same. I hope this helps you. That's how I solved my problem.